# How to remove vertical space while using display: inline with same tag or division?

Tags: html, css

I'm writing some static content based on heading tags and paragraph tags, the problem is that there is some question-answer part to display as an output. So, I have to use display:inline to make 'A.' and rest of content in one line. The code is for responsive devices and it perfect in web view but for mobile view, there is some vertical space while using display inline, and I want the symmetry among both. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
h3 {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;

    @include sm {
        font-size: 14px !important;
    }
}

.span-q,.span-a {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  @include sm {
    font-size: 14px !important;
  }
}

.p-a {
  display: inline;
}

.subpoint {
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;

    @include sm {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div className="text-left">
                <span className="span-a">A.&nbsp;</span><style={display:inline;}>Ordering food for train journeys online is amazingly simple. Just follow the following steps to book hygienic, fresh, and affordable food for delivery at your train seat.</p><br />
                <p className="subpoint">1. Enter your Train Name or number, 10-digit PNR number or desired station.</p>
                <p className="subpoint">2. Choose your favourite restaurant from the list displayed.</p>
                <p className="subpoint">3. Select your menu items from the chosen restaurant’s menu displayed.</p>
                <p className="subpoint">4. You can pay online or cash on delivery.</p>
                <p className="subpoint">5. Your order would get delivered right at your seat when the train arrives at the chosen railway station in your journey.</p>
</div>
```

[image: Please look image for reference]

Comment: The code isn't reproducible. But I think it's a problem of `line-height`. Furthermore, I advise you to style a `li` for displaying `A` and following letters

Comment: I try to update the code as per the image. Please check if possible.

Comment: Are you talking about the left side padding on your list? I don't quite understand why you won't use <ol> instead. Attached is a fiddle that lets you control the alignment using padding-left. https://jsfiddle.net/y13o7vg4/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather provide a way to debug it. Open the web inspector and navigate to any paragraph. You will notice that any paragraph has this user agent properties (it could vary among different browsers):

```
margin-block-start: 1em;
margin-block-end: 1em;
margin-inline-start: 0px;
margin-inline-end: 0px;
```

Just override `margin-block-start` and `margin-block-end`:

```
p {
    margin-block-start: 0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
    margin-inline-start: 0;
    margin-inline-end: 0;
}
```